# Java: How do I store List<Integer> in Queue?

Tags: java, list, queue

I want to create a `Queue` that stores The type `List<Integer>`.

I tried :

```java
Queue<List<Integer>> q = ...;
```

But, I don't know what should I press after `'='`. How to initialize the queue?

Comment: what have you tried so far and what is the error?

Comment: In java Linkedlist one of the queue implementation Queue<List<Integer>> queue = new LinkedList<>();

Comment: Do you want each of your Queue items to be a list of integers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use **LinkedList a**s the constructor class for interface **Queue**.

```
Queue<List<Integer>> q = new LinkedList<>();
```

Then you can call:

```
q.add(integerList);
q.remove();
```

ref: https://www.callicoder.com/java-queue/

According to the class hierarchy, you can use :

- PriorityQueue
- ArrayDequeue
- LinkedList

as classes to construct Queue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a queue like this

```html
Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<>();
```

hear T is any class